# Lodash : return first key of object whose value(i.e Array) has a given element (i.e string) in it

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object like:

```
var obj = {
  "01": ["a","b"],
  "03": ["c","d"],
  "04": ["e","c"]
};
```

and I know an array element ( say "c") of the object key's value then **How to find first key value i.e "03" using lodash without using if else?**

I tried like this using lodash and if else:

```
var rId = "";
_.forOwn(obj, function (array, id) {
     if (_.indexOf(array, "c") >= 0) {
           rId = id;
           return false;
     }
});

console.log(rId); // "03"
```

**Expected Result: first key i.e "03" if element matches else "".**

**After seeing comments:** Now I'm also curious to know about

Does I need to go with native javascript(hard to read program in the cases if we use more than 2 if blocks) or lodash way(easily readable program solution in one line)?

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: how about native javascript solution?

Comment: Without lodash: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/5pd8sq5g/

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Since you just want a way to be able to find a key using a simple Lodash command, the following should work:

```
_.findKey(obj, function(item) { return item.indexOf("c") !== -1; });
```

or, using ES6 syntax,

```
_.findKey(obj, (item) => (item.indexOf("c") !== -1));
```

This returns "03" for your example.

The predicate function - the second argument to `findKey()` - has automatic access to the value of the key. If nothing is found matching the predicate function, `undefined` is returned.

Documentation for `findKey()` is [here](https://lodash.com/docs#findKey).

---

Examples taken from the documentation:

```
var users = {
  'barney':  { 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  'fred':    { 'age': 40, 'active': false },
  'pebbles': { 'age': 1,  'active': true }
};

_.findKey(users, function(o) { return o.age < 40; });
// → 'barney' (iteration order is not guaranteed)

// The `_.matches` iteratee shorthand.
_.findKey(users, { 'age': 1, 'active': true });
// → 'pebbles'

// The `_.matchesProperty` iteratee shorthand.
_.findKey(users, ['active', false]);
// → 'fred'

// The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
_.findKey(users, 'active');
// → 'barney'
```

Comment: I'm doing node.js programming. Now I'm also curious to know about 

Does I need to go with native javascript(hard to read program) or lodash way(easily readable program)?

Comment: @SandeepSharma Use what you feel is best for your needs and requirements. If you already have Lodash, I think it's worth sticking with it. Lodash's API is what Javascript's semantics should have been. Since it's server-side, there are no _real_ arguments against using Lodash - on the client, it's a bulky library, but who cares about library size on the server? No one. There is a _tiny_ performance hit, but not enough to really make a difference.

Comment: @SandeepSharma Also, Javascript programs don't have to be hard to read. If your Javascript is hard to read, it's because you're making it needlessly complicated. JS can be as simple and clean to read as Lodash if you take the time to subscribe to proper patterns. Lodash _is_ Javascript, after all.

Comment: @SandeepSharma Anyway, if this answer correctly answers your original question, you should mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: you have fixed the item[0] to zeroth index.

Answer (score 11):

The irony is it is not any harder to implement without any libs.

```
Object.keys(obj).filter(x => obj[x].includes("c"))[0]
```

Comment: Good point! You could even use `.find(...)` instead of `.filter(...)[0]`: `Object.keys(obj).find(x => obj[x].includes("c"))`

Answer (score 1):

Here comes a single liner answer from the future. Currently only works in Firefox 47 on. Part of ES7 proposal.

```js
var obj = {
  "01": ["a","b"],
  "03": ["c","d"],
  "04": ["e","c"]
},
    res = Object.entries(obj).find(e => e[1].includes("c"))[0];
document.write(res);
```

Comment: I believe [is not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_Next_support_in_Mozilla) on a part of ES7 but rather ES8.

Comment: You probably shoud update `find` condition, since now you are not searching through the whole array, but only the first item.

Comment: @Роман Парадеев Yes you are right i have misunderstood the quotestion. I will correct accordingly. By the way your solution is perfect and deserves a +.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution: consider native Javascript approach using  `Object.keys` and `Array.some` functions:

```
var obj = {"01": ["a","b"],"03": ["c","d"],"04": ["e","c"]},
        search_str = "c", key = "";

Object.keys(obj).some(function(k) { return obj[k].indexOf(search_str) !== -1 && (key = k); });
// the same with ES6 syntax:
// Object.keys(obj).some((k) => obj[k].indexOf(search_str) !== -1 && (key = k));

console.log(key);  // "03"
```